# I want to display my products in my own template

Tags: magento2, product, custom-template, template-override

First, I am new to Magento 2. My aim is to achieve when products added in the backend I want it to show in my custom template.

Can anyone suggest some methods to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom module for this and create a custom block in `app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Product.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

And create your custom template in `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\your_template.php`

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());     
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Call your custom template in any xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product" name="custom.block" template="Vendor_Module:: your_template.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Or you can call your template in cms pages using

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product" template="Vendor_Module:: your_template.phtml"}}
```

Comment: where I have to call the template in which XML file

Comment: Where do you want to display the template?

Comment: like if I want to display in product page

Comment: create a file in `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml` each page will have some separate xml file name..You can see those in like `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout`